# AWS ruby on rails sample code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I am microbiology student and using Amazon EC2 to run a bunch of experiments. I am now working on creating a ruby on rails app that will act like a dashboard for my account, using this app I can view the existing instances, view the existing images, snapshots and I also want to have a feature of creating a new ec2 instance from an existing image. I am using the ruby sdk http://aws.amazon.com/articles/8621639827664165 that amazon provides. I am very new to ruby on rails programing, so wondering if people here know of some good sample code which shows interaction with amazon APIs using rails. I did go through some samples on the github site but did not find anything specific to interactions with amazon APIs. This will be very helpful, thanks a lot.

-Hilary

Comment: Which Amazon APIs? There's got to be at least twenty of them.

Comment: The EC2 APIs, starting a new instance from an existing snapshot, showing the list of instances that I am running. All the instances that i m running is being paid for by my lab, so I want to create a dashboard that clearly shows the list of instances running and also have one more feature to start a new EC2 instance from an existing image/snapshot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try the [right-aws](http://rightscale.rubyforge.org/right_aws_gem_doc/) gem which is a wrapper around the EC2 APIs that are part of AWS.